# 1D Wave Equation: Vertical Rod and Displacement vs. Textbook Solution

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, engineering

I am trying to setup Mathematica to analyze a vertical round rod under its own weight, fixed on one end free on the other.  I have the 1D wave equation and a distributed load to represent the self weight of the round rod.

[image: Vertical Rod Layout]

The problem is when I compare the Mathematica solution to the textbook solution the two do not agree.

Sample problem is given below.

```
Y = 199*^9; (*Young's modulus in Pa *)
\[Rho] = 7860; (* Steel density in kg/m^3*)
dia = 1/39.37; (* 1" dia converted to meters*)
c = Sqrt[Y/\[Rho]];
len = 1000; (*length in meters*)
tmax = 5; (* Max time for analysis*)
area = \[Pi]*dia^2/4; (*Round rod cross sectional area*)
wtfactor = \[Rho]*9.81*area/len;

frwt[x_] := \[Rho]*
   area*9.81*(1 - 
     x/len); (*Rod Self weight imposed as a distributed load*)
    nsol6 = NDSolve[{D[z[x, t], {t, 2}] == 
    c^2*D[z[x, t], {x, 2}] + frwt[x] + NeumannValue[0, x == len], 
   z[0, t] == 0}, 
     z[x, t], {x, 0, len}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 10}}]
fnnsol6[x_, t_] = nsol6[[1, 1, 2]]
Plot3D[fnnsol6[x, t], {x, 0, len}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotLabels -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> Automatic]

deltaL = ((\[Rho]*9.81*len^2)/(
 Y*2)) (*Textbook elongation for a vertical rod under self weight*)
calcdeltaL = 
 fnnsol6[len, 
  5] (*Calculated delta Length from PDE solution.  Should match \
textbook*)

deltaLfunc[x_, l_] := \[Rho]*9.81*
  x*(2*len - x)/(2*Y) (*Verified Correct*)
xydata = Thread[{Range[0, 1000, 100], 
    deltaLfunc[x, 1] /. {x -> Range[0, 1000, 100]}}];

Show[Plot[fnnsol6[x, 0], {x, 0, len}, PlotLabels -> {"PDE Val"}, 
  PlotRange -> All
  ],
 ListLinePlot[xydata, PlotStyle -> Green, PlotLabels -> {"Correct"}]]
```

If you've read this far, thank you.

In summary my question is:  Is this a Mathematica issue or a PDE setup problem?  The PDE is right out of a textbook so I don't think that's the problem but Mathematica gives no errors and I am out of troubleshooting ideas so looking for some help.

Thank You

Comment: Can't copy this `[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({t, 2}\)]\(z[x, t]\)\) == c^2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({x, 2}\)]\(z[x, t]\)\) + frwt[x] + `  it shows up all mangled on my notebook. try to copy/paste using plain text from the InputForm version of the cell. Make sure to make copy of it first.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I don't know what's going on.  I copied it into my Mathematica and it worked fine.  Let me test and I will edit.

Comment: Before you copy it, make a copy of the cell to another empty notebook (so you do not lose your original formating) Then convert the new cell to INPUT FORM first. Then copy the result as plain text to here.

Comment: I edited so I hope it works better now.  Thanks for pointing out my error!

Comment: It is still not working. `Reverse[a]` there is no `a` anywhere to reverse. It is always best to try your code before posting it from clean kernel.

Comment: **clean kernel**  is key!  I tested it but unfortunately has another version open.  Apologies as I thought I had checked, but not correctly.

Comment: Why do write `deltaLfunc[x_, l_] := \[Rho]*9.81*
  x*(2*len - x)/(2*Y) (*Verified Correct*)`  and not use `l` in RHS? you are passing `l` to the function as second argument, where is it used in RHS?

Comment: also your `frwt[x_]` seems wrong. At x=0 it should be zero and at x=len, it should be the full weigth of the beam.  Try to plugin  zero for x in your definition and see if you get zero. You do not. Assuming x=0 at top.

Comment: frwt[0]=39.=Total rod weight per unit length.  x=0 is fixed end so that seems right.  frwt[len]=0 which is the free end.

Comment: As I said, I assumed x=0 at top, which is really the common way to do these things. No one puts x=0 at the free end (where it can move) and go back to the top where it is fixed. But as long as you are consistent, that is OK. It is just not how this is normally done, that is all.

Comment: Keep in mind that with `Method -> {"FiniteElement",...` you solve this as a stationary PDE, thought his is a time dependent PDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After small modification we have coincidence for `calcdeltaL` and `deltaL` with all digits:

```
Y = 199*^9;(*Young's modulus in Pa*)\[Rho] = 7860;(*Steel density in \
kg/m^3*)dia = 1/39.37; nu = .0;(*1" dia converted to meters*)c = 
 Sqrt[Y/\[Rho]]; g = 9.81;
len = 1000;(*length in meters*)tmax = 5;(*Max time for analysis*)area \
= \[Pi]*dia^2/
   4;(*Round rod cross sectional area*)wtfactor = \[Rho]*9.81*area/len;

frwt[x_] := \[Rho] area*9.81*(1 - 
    x/len);(*Rod Self weight imposed as a distributed load*)nsol6 = 
 NDSolve[{D[z[x, t], t, t] - c^2 D[z[x, t], {x, 2}] - g == 
    NeumannValue[0, x == len], 
   DirichletCondition[z[x, t] == 0, x == 0]}, 
  z[x, t], {x, 0, len}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 10}}];
fnnsol6[x_, t_] = nsol6[[1, 1, 2]];
Plot3D[fnnsol6[x, t], {x, 0, len}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]

deltaL = ((\[Rho]*9.81*
     len^2)/(Y*2)) (*Textbook elongation for a vertical rod under \
self weight*)
calcdeltaL = 
 fnnsol6[len, 
  5] (*Calculated delta Length from PDE solution.Should match\
textbook*)

deltaLfunc[x_, l_] := \[Rho]*9.81*
  x*(2*len - x)/(2*Y) (*Verified Correct*)
xydata = Thread[{Range[0, 1000, 100], 
    deltaLfunc[x, 1] /. {x -> Range[0, 1000, 100]}}];

Show[Plot[fnnsol6[x, 0], {x, 0, len}, 
  PlotLabel -> "PDE Val and Correct (dashed line)", PlotRange -> All],
  ListLinePlot[xydata, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Green}]]
```

Length `0.193735` and `0.193735`.
Visualization
[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Absolute genius @Alex-Trounev  Thank you very much.  I need to go read why g replaces my distributed load but clearly you solved in minutes what I spent countless hours on.  Greatly appreciated....Thank you, thank you!!!

Comment: Why do you solve this as a stationary PDE and not a time dependant one?

Comment: @wpilgri You are welcome!

Comment: @user21 For time dependence there is no reason, since we are looking stationary solution to compare with textbook.

Comment: @user21 Baby steps.  I tried to solve it and look at the stationary solution before getting more complicated.  If I couldn't get stationary right, why proceed is my thinking.